# Is there a C# function, similar to OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog, that allows only the browsing/selection of a local drive?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, backup

Using: Visual Studio 2017 (Language: C#) (WPF Application)

The application I am working on needs to enable the user to browse a "file explorer" window, similar to what is shown during a new OpenFileDialog or FolderBrowserDialog, and allow them to select **only** a local drive.

The selection of the drive would ideally return the drive location path so that it can go through a "data backup". This data backup would consist of copying the contents of the drive selection to another drive/flash-drive location.

Any insight or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, there is not a control that allows users to only select local drives. You could create one or you can check if the returned path of a FolderBrowserDialog is a local drive, if not you can display an error messeage.

Comment: U can use `SaveFileDialog` or even `FolderBrowserDialog` itself

Comment: Why open a dialog to select a drive letter. I would use a dropdown list with the available drive letters.

Comment: A dropdown like @dcg suggested, or heck a simple custom modal dialog if you want, is probably you best bet. You're not going to find the control you're looking for out of the box, and adding such restriction to the OFD or FBD controls just seems like there's potential to get a little too messy.

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog has a property called RootFolder. You can set it to Environment.SpcialFolder.MyComputer. This exclude the possibility to search for network folders. However is not fool proof because if your user has mapped drives they will be visible.